# Is there any way to tell user how many rows are in a table?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have a table full of names and I want users to know how many names are there.

What would be the output process be?

Comment: You mean how many names in total, or how many names matching some criteria?

Answer (score 5):

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT Count(*) FROM table') or die('error');
$count = mysql_result($result, 0, 'count(*)');
echo $count;
```

Comment: If I wanted to output it in plan text how would I?

Comment: If you wanted that, Charles, you should hire a developer!

Comment: I've edited Dan's answer to show how it needs to be done but I agree 100% with will, you either need to hire a developer or spend some time learning the language first, including the potential security implications of all your actions, and this needs to be done long before any website is made public.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table; would be slightly faster.

Comment: @Unkwntech - thanks for the edit. @eyze - yes, presuming id is the primary key (but from info given there was no way of knowing)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted unique names only,

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name_column) FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're filling the table from an array, you can use `count($array)` in your php code to list the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $r = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table;');
    $v = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
    echo 'There are ' . $v['cnt'] . ' rows in the table.';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're implementing some kind of pagination and want to also show the total amount of records you could use [MySQL's FOUND_ROWS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).
e.g.

```
$start = $page*$itemsPerPage;
$query = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
        x,y,z
    FROM
        foo
    LIMIT
        $start, $itemsPerPage
";
$result = mysql_query($query, $mysql) or die(mysql_error());
while( false!==($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) ) {
    echo
        htmlspecialchars($row['x'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'), ' ',
        htmlspecialchars($row['y'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'), ' ',
        htmlspecialchars($row['z'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'), ' ',
        "<br />\n";
}

$query = 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS()';
$result = mysql_query($query, $mysql) or die(mysql_error());
$total = mysql_result($result, 0, 0);
echo $total, ' record(s) found';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
$sql = 'SELECT Count(`id`) as c FROM table';
$ok = mysql_query($sql);
if($ok){
   $v = mysql_fetch_assoc($ok);
   echo 'There are '.$v['c'].' names in the table.';
}else{
   echo 'MySQL error: '.mysql_error();
}
```